# No module named 'backend.settings' debug pycharm

Tags: python, django, pycharm, environment-variables

I am using Pycharm and Django. I have a virtual environment (`tour of heroes`). When I run `python3 manage.py runserver` from the terminal (with activated virtualenv) the project runs fine. When I try to run the project from the Pycharm Debugger i get the error:

`ModuleNotFoundError("No module named backend.settings",)`

In the **Edit Configurations** for the Pycharm debugger I have the python interpreter set to the correct `tour of heroes` virtualenv. The environment variables:

`DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` = `backend.settings`,
`PYTHONUNBUFFERED` = `1`

I am running a similar project with a different environment and i double checked and compared all the settings and variables etc and the other project debugs just fine. I dont get why if I am using the same venv than running in terminal or debugger mode should both work...

my **settings.py**

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '#__2nx&dsjk3)8yx&nut&p7c8rc8zg_cm$bwx*sbrucqp2zu2f'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'heroes',
    'rest_framework',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'backend.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'backend.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

my **wsgi.py**

```
import os, sys

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'backend.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: Make sure that the project (i.e. the one that contains `manage.py` is on the Python path in PyCharm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure your Django project, go to:

```
Preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> Django
```

Set your project root, settings file and manage.py script. You probably will also need to configure the template language at:

```
Preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> Python Template Language
```

Selecte Django as Template language

Comment: thanks so much. For some reason it was not letting me change anything in the Django box, all it said was "nothing to show". It started working after playing around with it i was able to set the correct directory, this what the issue.